# get all items from podio api

Tags: javascript, node.js, podio

I want to fetch items of app from podio in node js 
here is the code that am using to get items,

```
 podio.authenticateWithCredentials(username, password, function () {
        podio.request('GET', '/item/app/{app_id}/filters').then(function (responseData) {
          console.log(responseData);
          res.send(responseData);
        }).catch(function (e) {
          console.log('0-0-0-0', e);
          res.send(e);
        });
      });
```

an i always get this error

```
"No matching operation could be found. The path '/item/app/{app_id}/filters' was not found.."
```

is there any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only replace  `{app_id}`    with the  app id To get the app id and token:

Go to your app on Podio
Click the little wrench in the sidebar
Select the "Developer" option near the bottom
On the following page you can get the app id and token

[image]

Comment: Thankx fro your response but i tried to find Developer option but There is no developer option in menu

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace app_id in this url `'/item/app/{app_id}/filters'` with actual url you must have got from podio api.

Comment: yes am using my client_id in place of app_id but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

You should use **POST** instead of **GET** method